# Python COM client communicating with Autohotkey COM server

Tags: python, com, autohotkey, win32com

I'm trying to control autohotkey script from python script using COM. I discovered COM today so I'm still little confused. My current code works without no errors, but I don't get any result. When I run the python script after I've started the autohotkey COM server, I get this output: `result:`. So, empty output. Also, a message box should appear but it doesn't.

I'm not sure if this is the right approach, but I checked registry editor and couldn't find HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{4F00ABC1-ACAE-4D12-835D-A012302C7443}

I've tried running both scripts as administrator, but that doesn't help. I can't find any help online either. What am I doing wrong? Is the issue in the client or server side? Should I use different function on the client side? Am I doing everything wrong or should I use a completely different way to communicate between autohotkey and python?

I generated my python COM client code with ChatGPT because I couldn't find any online help for that, but at least the code runs without errors. Please don't blame me.
This is my current python COM client code:

```py
import win32com.client

server_name = "{4F00ABC1-ACAE-4D12-835D-A012302C7443}"

obj = win32com.client.Dispatch(server_name)

result = obj.Message()
print('result:', result)

obj = None
```

This is my autohotkey COM server code that I found from [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6148):

```
#Persistent

ObjRegisterActive(_obj, "{4F00ABC1-ACAE-4D12-835D-A012302C7443}")

class _obj {
    Message()
    {
        MsgBox, this message box never shows :(
        return "test"
    }
}

/*
    ObjRegisterActive(Object, CLSID, Flags:=0)
    
        Registers an object as the active object for a given class ID.
        Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.17+; may crash earlier versions.
    
    Object:
            Any AutoHotkey object.
    CLSID:
            A GUID or ProgID of your own making.
            Pass an empty string to revoke (unregister) the object.
    Flags:
            One of the following values:
              0 (ACTIVEOBJECT_STRONG)
              1 (ACTIVEOBJECT_WEAK)
            Defaults to 0.
    
    (I removed google url shortener links cuz SOF doesnt allow them)
*/
ObjRegisterActive(Object, CLSID, Flags:=0) {
    static cookieJar := {}
    if (!CLSID) {
        if (cookie := cookieJar.Remove(Object)) != ""
            DllCall("oleaut32\RevokeActiveObject", "uint", cookie, "ptr", 0)
        return
    }
    if cookieJar[Object]
        throw Exception("Object is already registered", -1)
    VarSetCapacity(_clsid, 16, 0)
    if (hr := DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr", CLSID, "ptr", &_clsid)) < 0
        throw Exception("Invalid CLSID", -1, CLSID)
    hr := DllCall("oleaut32\RegisterActiveObject"
        , "ptr", &Object, "ptr", &_clsid, "uint", Flags, "uint*", cookie
        , "uint")
    if hr < 0
        throw Exception(format("Error 0x{:x}", hr), -1)
    cookieJar[Object] := cookie
}
```